# dealing with unix timestamps in php?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Say for example i had a unix timestamp `1345810244` , what i wanted to do is have a function to check whether this timestamp has the same date as today i.e.

```
function isToday($unixTimestamp) {

   if ($unixTimestamp == (today){
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

Im so new to dealing unix timestamps, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) == date('Y-m-d')) {
    // yes, it's the same day
}
```

Comment: can you explain your answer, i really want to understand this thanks :)

Comment: `date` formats the time into the given format, here YYYY-MM-DD. If given no timestamp, it takes todays date. So you end up comparing two strings like "2012-08-24".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without DateTime functions, the easiest way (probably not the most accurate, due to missing time zone offsets) would be:

```
function isToday($unixTimestamp)
{
    return date('d.m.Y', $unixTimestamp) === date('d.m.Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Date and time from unix timestamp

```
$timestamp = "1340892242";
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
    $time = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);
    echo $date;
    echo $time;
```